# Android application suddenly killed by Application manager and restarted without any error

Tags: android

starting from this mine previous ([My Android app's singleton gets re-initialized while app is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764025/my-android-apps-singleton-gets-re-initialized-while-app-is-running)) post, I've made several experiments to understand why my application dies after (about) 20 times that I move back and forward between 2 activities (via intent). 
At first, I thought that it could be a heap memory problem (because the logcat was always showing "grow heap size.." till 60-70MB that app crashed, always without any kind of error, either OutOfMemory), but also now with 16-18MB always crashes at the same point. I've also removed actrionbarsherlock and sliding menu by J. Feinstein, created a class to manage bitmap and drawable cache, store downloaded bitmaps into the internal memory, call the famous "unbindDrawables" method and the garbageCollector in every activity in the onPause and onDestroy methods, yet my app always dies while navigating between activities.

Anyone can give me any hint? I really can get out of this problem, without any logged error it's really difficult for me to understand where is the bug.
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

P.S. if any piece of code is need just ask.

UPDATE 1: Logcat

```
07-29 09:45:41.588: I/dalvikvm-heap(7277): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.894MB for 251453-byte allocation 
07-29 09:45:41.588: D/dalvikvm(7240): GC_CONCURRENT freed 474K, 8% free 7368K/8007K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:41.619: E/AlarmManagerService(211): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 833616.841000000
07-29 09:45:41.619: I/SysScopeService(7324): registerAlarm, interval:86400000
07-29 09:45:41.619: W/SysScopeService(7324): onCreate
07-29 09:45:41.619: W/SysScopeService(7324): onStart Intent { act=com.sec.intent.action.SYSSCOPE flg=0x4 (has extras) }
07-29 09:45:41.619: I/SysScopeService(7324): periodic:true
07-29 09:45:41.619: W/SysScopeService(7324): setState state=1
07-29 09:45:41.635: D/dalvikvm(7277): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 255K, 10% free 8765K/9671K, paused 30ms
07-29 09:45:41.635: W/SysScopeService(7324): handleMessage
07-29 09:45:41.635: W/SysScopeService(7324): current state = SYSSCOPE_STATE_INIT, next state = SYDSCOPE_STATE_RUN
07-29 09:45:41.674: D/dalvikvm(7277): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 240K, 7% free 9021K/9671K, paused 26ms
07-29 09:45:41.744: D/dalvikvm(7240): GC_CONCURRENT freed 486K, 8% free 7393K/8007K, paused 1ms+1ms
07-29 09:45:41.744: D/DeviceInfo(211): Trying to connect to SysScope Service
07-29 09:45:41.807: I/ActivityManager(211): Start proc app.processName for service hostingNameStr: pid=7350 uid=1000 gids={3003, 1015, 1023, 3001, 3002, 2001, 1006, 1007, 1001, 3007}
07-29 09:45:41.846: D/dalvikvm(7277): GC_CONCURRENT freed 376K, 5% free 9462K/9927K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:41.862: D/dalvikvm(211): GC_EXPLICIT freed 934K, 30% free 19850K/27975K, paused 3ms+21ms
07-29 09:45:41.869: D/dalvikvm(7240): GC_CONCURRENT freed 513K, 8% free 7380K/8007K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:41.893: D/dalvikvm(98): GC_EXPLICIT freed 39K, 5% free 6646K/6979K, paused 1ms+21ms
07-29 09:45:41.940: D/EnterpriseSysScope(7350): onCreate()
07-29 09:45:41.940: D/EnterpriseSysScope(7350): onBind()
07-29 09:45:41.940: D/DeviceInfo(211): SysScope Service connected
07-29 09:45:41.947: D/dalvikvm(98): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 5% free 6646K/6979K, paused 3ms+1ms
07-29 09:45:41.971: D/dalvikvm(98): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 5% free 6646K/6979K, paused 1ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:42.018: D/dalvikvm(7240): GC_CONCURRENT freed 494K, 8% free 7395K/8007K, paused 1ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:42.057: D/dalvikvm(7324): GC_CONCURRENT freed 368K, 7% free 6782K/7239K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:42.072: D/dalvikvm(7324): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libcordon.so 0x412667c8, skipping init
07-29 09:45:42.072: W/SysScopeService(7324): setState state=2
07-29 09:45:42.072: W/SysScopeService(7324): handleMessage
07-29 09:45:42.072: W/SysScopeService(7324): current state = SYDSCOPE_STATE_RUN, next state = SYDSCOPE_STATE_DONE
07-29 09:45:42.112: D/dalvikvm(7240): GC_CONCURRENT freed 482K, 8% free 7417K/8007K, paused 3ms+1ms
07-29 09:45:42.174: I/DIOTEK(7240): ET9KRUDBInit : 2
07-29 09:45:42.182: D/dalvikvm(7277): GC_CONCURRENT freed 210K, 3% free 10205K/10503K, paused 2ms+3ms
07-29 09:45:42.330: D/SysScopeService(7324): CPU usage : 100
07-29 09:45:42.330: D/SysScopeService(7324): Sleep 10 secs
07-29 09:45:42.354: D/dalvikvm(7240): GC_CONCURRENT freed 574K, 9% free 7408K/8071K, paused 1ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:42.479: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41e6ed08 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.Dashboard paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.479: I/ActivityManager(211): Process com.example.fantacalcioTSL (pid 6053) has died.
07-29 09:45:42.487: D/dalvikvm(7277): GC_CONCURRENT freed 727K, 8% free 10710K/11527K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:42.502: W/InputDispatcher(211): channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
07-29 09:45:42.502: E/InputDispatcher(211): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-29 09:45:42.502: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.510: I/power(211): *** release_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1 
07-29 09:45:42.510: W/InputDispatcher(211): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '41b42898 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.Home (server)'
07-29 09:45:42.510: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.510: D/PowerManagerService(211): releaseDVFSLockLocked : all DVFS_MIN_LIMIT are released 
07-29 09:45:42.510: W/ActivityManager(211): mDVFSLock.release()
07-29 09:45:42.510: W/ActivityManager(211): Force removing ActivityRecord{4219ef40 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa}: app died, no saved state
07-29 09:45:42.510: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41b42898 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.Home paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.510: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41b13c68 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.518: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.518: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.518: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41599a78 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.Login paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.526: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.526: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.526: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.526: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41a40c98 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.526: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{419fbf18 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.526: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{42057a20 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.Dashboard paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.533: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.533: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.533: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.533: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.533: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41e80d98 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.533: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41f8acc0 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.533: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{4191ae50 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.533: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{416416b0 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.541: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.541: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.541: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.541: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{416feac8 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.541: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41b40f40 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.541: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{42061220 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.Dashboard paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.549: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.549: E/InputDispatcher(211): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=341, events=0x8
07-29 09:45:42.549: W/InputDispatcher(211): channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
07-29 09:45:42.549: E/InputDispatcher(211): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-29 09:45:42.549: W/InputDispatcher(211): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '421c9780 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa (server)'
07-29 09:45:42.549: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.549: E/InputDispatcher(211): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=348, events=0x8
07-29 09:45:42.549: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.549: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41f47db0 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.549: I/WindowManager(211): WINDOW DIED Window{41b42898 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.Home paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.549: I/WindowManager(211): WINDOW DIED Window{421c9780 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.549: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{4168a000 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.549: W/InputManagerService(211): Client died receiving input method InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@42010608 com.sec.android.inputmethod/.SamsungKeypad #1082}
07-29 09:45:42.549: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{42055c40 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.557: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.557: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.557: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.557: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.557: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41a2f648 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.557: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41fc5948 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.557: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41e9b098 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.565: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.565: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.565: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.565: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.565: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.565: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41ecb0b8 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.565: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41a04c50  com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.565: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{419fc468 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.565: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41fbc650 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.572: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.572: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41feb2a0 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.580: W/InputDispatcher(211): channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
07-29 09:45:42.580: E/InputDispatcher(211): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-29 09:45:42.596: W/WindowManager(211): Failed looking up window
07-29 09:45:42.596: W/WindowManager(211): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@416d51c0 does not exist
07-29 09:45:42.596: W/WindowManager(211):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7722)
07-29 09:45:42.596: W/WindowManager(211):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7713)
07-29 09:45:42.596: W/WindowManager(211):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1530)
07-29 09:45:42.596: W/WindowManager(211):   at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:417)
07-29 09:45:42.596: W/WindowManager(211):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-29 09:45:42.596: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.596: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.596: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: null
07-29 09:45:42.596: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41f4b478 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.596: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{41b22590 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.604: W/InputDispatcher(211): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4146cbf8 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa (server)'
07-29 09:45:42.604: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.604: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.604: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.604: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.604: I/WindowManager(211): WIN DEATH: Window{4146cbf8 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.604: W/ActivityManager(211): Force removing ActivityRecord{41fc6668 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.AcquistoGiocatori}: app died, no saved state
07-29 09:45:42.604: D/DEFERED_APP_VISIBILITY(211): tweaking closing app
07-29 09:45:42.604: D/DEFERED_APP_VISIBILITY(211): tweaking closing app
07-29 09:45:42.604: V/WindowManager(211): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=-1, last=3); user=3  mLidOpen=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=1 sensorRotation=-1
07-29 09:45:42.612: E/InputDispatcher(211): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=404, events=0x8
07-29 09:45:42.612: I/power(211): *** acquire_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1  freq : 1008000 
07-29 09:45:42.612: I/WindowManager(211): WINDOW DIED Window{4146cbf8 com.example.fantacalcioTSL/com.fantacalcioTSL.activities.GestioneRosa paused=false}
07-29 09:45:42.612: D/PowerManagerService(211): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1008000  uid : 1000  pid : 211  tag : ActivityManager
07-29 09:45:42.612: W/ActivityManager(211): mDVFSLock.acquire()
07-29 09:45:42.635: D/dalvikvm(7363): Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-29 09:45:42.635: I/ActivityManager(211): Start proc app.processName for activity hostingNameStr: pid=7363 uid=10128 gids={3003}
07-29 09:45:42.666: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.674: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.682: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.697: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.705: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.705: V/WindowManager(211): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=1, last=3); user=3  mLidOpen=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=1 sensorRotation=-1
07-29 09:45:42.744: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.752: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.862: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.869: I/Application(7363): onCreate
07-29 09:45:42.869: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.869: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_CONCURRENT freed 147K, 4% free 6975K/7239K, paused 3ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:42.869: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.877: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.893: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.908: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.924: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.940: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.955: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.971: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 179K, 7% free 7123K/7623K, paused 17ms
07-29 09:45:42.971: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:42.987: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:43.002: D/dalvikvm(7277): GC_CONCURRENT freed 315K, 4% free 11763K/12167K, paused 2ms+4ms
07-29 09:45:43.002: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:43.018: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 108K, 6% free 7177K/7623K, paused 17ms
07-29 09:45:43.018: I/dalvikvm-heap(7363): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.331MB for 248290-byte allocation
07-29 09:45:43.018: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:43.041: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:43.041: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 161K, 8% free 7258K/7879K, paused 19ms
07-29 09:45:43.057: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:43.072: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:43.072: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 242K, 9% free 7227K/7879K, paused 17ms
07-29 09:45:43.088: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:43.088: D/KeyguardViewMediator(211): setHidden false
07-29 09:45:43.135: D/gp.PicasaPhotoCP(7277): set fsid first time:-1
07-29 09:45:43.135: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 296K, 8% free 7293K/7879K, paused 19ms
07-29 09:45:43.182: D/dalvikvm(7277): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.google.android.apps.plus/lib/libwebp_android.so 0x41265dd0
07-29 09:45:43.190: D/dalvikvm(7277): Added shared lib /data/data/com.google.android.apps.plus/lib/libwebp_android.so 0x41265dd0
07-29 09:45:43.190: D/dalvikvm(7277): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.google.android.apps.plus/lib/libwebp_android.so 0x41265dd0, skipping init
07-29 09:45:43.190: D/dalvikvm(7277): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.google.android.apps.plus/lib/libplus_jni_v8.so 0x41265dd0
07-29 09:45:43.190: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 165K, 7% free 7376K/7879K, paused 17ms
07-29 09:45:43.205: D/dalvikvm(7277): Added shared lib /data/data/com.google.android.apps.plus/lib/libplus_jni_v8.so 0x41265dd0
07-29 09:45:43.205: D/dalvikvm(7277): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.google.android.apps.plus/lib/libplus_jni_v8.so 0x41265dd0, skipping init
07-29 09:45:43.205: I/NativeLibrarySupport(7277): Native WEBP decoder, version=0.3.0
07-29 09:45:43.205: I/NativeLibrarySupport(7277): Native networking disabled
07-29 09:45:43.237: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 148K, 6% free 7450K/7879K, paused 15ms
07-29 09:45:43.237: I/dalvikvm-heap(7363): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.570MB for 219686-byte allocation
07-29 09:45:43.252: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 222K, 9% free 7442K/8135K, paused 14ms
07-29 09:45:43.276: D/dalvikvm(7277): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 847K, 9% free 11616K/12679K, paused 53ms
07-29 09:45:43.276: I/dalvikvm-heap(7277): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.541MB for 1165488-byte allocation
07-29 09:45:43.307: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_CONCURRENT freed 260K, 7% free 7588K/8135K, paused 1ms+1ms
07-29 09:45:43.322: D/dalvikvm(7277): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 8% free 12752K/13831K, paused 48ms
07-29 09:45:43.369: D/dalvikvm(7277): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 12752K/13831K, paused 45ms
07-29 09:45:43.377: I/dalvikvm-heap(7277): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.418MB for 1971216-byte allocation
07-29 09:45:43.424: D/dalvikvm(7277): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 14677K/15815K, paused 47ms
07-29 09:45:43.432: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_CONCURRENT freed 433K, 8% free 7611K/8199K, paused 2ms+1ms
07-29 09:45:43.471: D/dalvikvm(7277): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 16096K/16839K, paused 48ms
07-29 09:45:43.487: D/STATUSBAR-NotificationService(211): cancelNotification - pkg:com.google.android.apps.plus, id:2131296365, tag:InstantShare
07-29 09:45:43.487: D/STATUSBAR-NotificationService(211): cancelNotification - pkg:com.google.android.apps.plus, id:2131296365, tag:InstantShare
07-29 09:45:43.549: I/ActivityManager(211): Start proc app.processName for service hostingNameStr: pid=7379 uid=10020 gids={3003, 1015, 1023}
07-29 09:45:43.619: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_CONCURRENT freed 339K, 6% free 7769K/8263K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:43.682: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 227K, 8% free 7783K/8391K, paused 29ms
07-29 09:45:43.682: I/dalvikvm-heap(7363): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.765MB for 82392-byte allocation
07-29 09:45:43.690: D/dalvikvm(7379): GC_CONCURRENT freed 151K, 4% free 6999K/7239K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:43.721: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 7864K/8519K, paused 22ms
07-29 09:45:43.799: I/ActivityThread(7379): Pub com.google.android.maps.OfflineIndexProvider: com.google.googlenav.provider.OfflineIndexProvider
07-29 09:45:43.815: I/ActivityThread(7379): Pub com.google.android.maps.SearchHistoryProvider: com.google.googlenav.provider.SearchHistoryProvider
07-29 09:45:43.815: I/ActivityThread(7379): Pub com.google.android.maps.SuggestionProvider: com.google.googlenav.suggest.android.SuggestContentProvider
07-29 09:45:43.830: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_CONCURRENT freed 382K, 8% free 7889K/8519K, paused 1ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:43.846: I/ActivityThread(7379): Pub com.google.android.maps.LayerInfoProvider: com.google.googlenav.layer.LayerInfoProvider
07-29 09:45:43.877: I/ActivityThread(7379): Pub com.google.android.maps.TrafficAppWidgetProvider: com.google.googlenav.appwidget.traffic.TrafficAppWidgetProvider
07-29 09:45:43.877: I/ActivityThread(7379): Pub com.google.android.maps.LocalActivePlacesProvider: com.google.googlenav.provider.LocalActivePlacesProvider
07-29 09:45:43.877: I/ActivityThread(7379): Pub com.google.android.maps.StarredItemProvider:   com.google.googlenav.provider.StarredItemProvider
07-29 09:45:43.901: D/dalvikvm(7379): GC_CONCURRENT freed 217K, 5% free 7262K/7623K, paused 2ms+3ms
07-29 09:45:43.916: I/ActivityManager(211): Start proc app.processName for content provider hostingNameStr: pid=7391 uid=10007 gids={3003, 1015, 1023, 1007, 1006, 2001, 3006}
07-29 09:45:43.979: I/ActivityThread(7391): Pub com.google.settings: com.google.android.gsf.settings.GoogleSettingsProvider
07-29 09:45:44.041: D/dalvikvm(7363): GC_CONCURRENT freed 287K, 6% free 8027K/8519K, paused 1ms+2ms
07-29 09:45:44.065: I/ActivityThread(7391): Pub subscribedfeeds: com.google.android.gsf.subscribedfeeds.SubscribedFeedsProvider
07-29 09:45:44.080: I/USER(7363): user inizializzato (INIT)
07-29 09:45:44.127: I/ActivityThread(7391): Pub com.google.contacts.gal.provider: com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts.GalProvider
07-29 09:45:44.151: I/ActivityThread(7391): Pub com.google.android.gsf.gservices: com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider
07-29 09:45:44.158: I/GservicesProvider(7391): Gservices pushing to system: true; secure: true
07-29 09:45:44.158: I/ActivityThread(7391): Pub com.google.android.providers.talk: com.google.android.gsf.talk.TalkProvider
```

Comment: You almost certainly have an OOM error.  Examine logcat *carefully*

Comment: I've added the logcat. You can see at "09:45:42.869: I/Application(7363): onCreate" means that the object application method onCreate() is called; and at "09:45:42.479: I/ActivityManager(211): Process com.example.fantacalcioTSL (pid 6053) has died." should mean that the app gets killed. So there must be something before that causes the crash, but as you can see there's no error. Anyway, thank you Simon for your help.

Comment: @Axce, have you identified the rot cause of this issue, i am facing the same issue but not able to identify the root cause of this problem. Please share solutions if you have identified.

Comment: I had identified the root cause of rhe issue and its related to custom view and some time it takes more time in onMeasure which results the closing of application